# Attempting to create array of values less than -3 in Python

Tags: python, list

Trying to understand why my code fails here. I have tested each line and it appears to fail with my append function, but I went through the documentation and I'm not sure how to fix the issue?

The problem is to create a new array(res) of the index of values in input array (x) where the value is less than -3. Input array has a few thousand records, so if there is a more pythonic approach that I am missing, I would love input. Many thanks.

```
def three(x):
    res=[]
    for v in range(len(x)):
       i = x[v]
       if v < -3:
           res.append(i)
    return res
```

Edited code indentation

Comment: Is that how your indentation looks actually?

Comment: What is this `data` variable, is it a global?

Comment: No, sorry, it ate my indentation and I have corrected it. Thanks you.

Comment: uh, do you mean `if i < -3:`?  `v` will never be less than zero.

Comment: Got it, I was using len(x) incorrectly that caused it to use the indexes rather than values. Louis' edited solution is much more elegant than my idea. Cheers all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a very pythonic way to solve this:  [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)!

```
res = [ind for ind, v in enumerate(x) if v < -3]
```

Your problem is that you check to see if `v` is less than -3.  However, `v` is a number in `range(len(x))`, which is always > 0.  You should've checked `if i < -3`, and then appended `v` because `v` actually stored the index (not the value).

Comment: This actually does not work. Your `res` will be a list of the values, not their indexes.

You gotta do `res = [i for i, v in enumerate(x) if v < -3]`

Comment: @Hamatti I appreciate the catch.  I misread OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `for v in range(len(x)):`, `v` takes on integer values from `0` to `len(x)-1`.  These values will never be less than -3, so your `res.append` line never executes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using filter() as it's cleaner:

```
>>> x = range(-100, 100, 1)
>>> filter(lambda f: f < -3, x)
[-100, -99, -98, -97, -96, -95, -94, -93, -92, -91, -90, -89, -88, -87, -86, -85, -84, -83, -82, -81, -80, -79, -78, -77, -76, -75, -74, -73, -72, -71, -70, -69, -68, -67, -66, -65, -64, -63, -62, -61, -60, -59, -58, -57, -56, -55, -54, -53, -52, -51, -50, -49, -48, -47, -46, -45, -44, -43, -42, -41, -40, -39, -38, -37, -36, -35, -34, -33, -32, -31, -30, -29, -28, -27, -26, -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4]
>>>
```

Edit:

As Hamatti correctly pointed, the code above do not output the indexes as OP requested. Here goes a another way to do it using map() and enumerate():

```
map(lambda i: i[0], filter(lambda f: f[1] < -3, enumerate(x)))
```

Comment: This one only returns list of values, not indices OP was interested in.